# Laravel reseeding a table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

In Laravel how would you reseed a database? Without losing existing data / migrations?

I have a RoleAndPermissionSeeder.php with Spatie's Permission package:

```
namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\PermissionRegistrar;

class RoleAndPermissionSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        // Reset cached roles and permissions
        app()[PermissionRegistrar::class]->forgetCachedPermissions();

        $permissions = [
            'articles create',
            'articles delete',
            'articles read',
            'articles update',
            'dashboard read',
        ];

        foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
            Permission::create(['name' => $permission]);
        }
        // =======================================================================

        $admin = Role::create(['name' => 'admin']);
        $member = Role::create(['name' => 'member']);
        Role::create(['name' => 'super-admin']);

        // =======================================================================

        $admin_permissions = [
            'articles read',
            'dashboard read',
        ];

        $member_permissions = [
            'dashboard read',
        ];

        $admin->syncPermissions($admin_permissions);
        $member->syncPermissions($member_permissions);
    }
}
```

After creating a new migration for a blog I have added extra permissions to read, update the blog and so on. How would I reseed this file so that the new permissions get added?

Comment: Read [Running Seeders](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding#running-seeders), "_you may use the --class option to specify a specific seeder class to run individually_"

Comment: @brombeer thanks for your reply, I have seen and read the documentation on seeders but when I try to reseed it will throw an error saying the data already exists. Or would you, just like a migration create a new seeder for these occasions?

Comment: @Ronald I would think you should modify your seeder to check what data is already there and then only insert the missing ones

Comment: You could use `firstOrCreate` instead of `create` in your seeder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your seeder class has `firstOrCreate` instead of `create`

```
foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
    Permission::firstOrCreate(['name' => $permission]);
}
// =======================================================================
$admin = Role::firstOrCreate(['name' => 'admin']);
$member = Role::firstOrCreate(['name' => 'member']);
Role::firstOrCreate(['name' => 'super-admin']);
```

It will not duplicate the data. If `syncPermissions` uses `sync` behind the scenes, then it shouldn't be a problem.

As long as you don't drop the table, you shouldn't lose any data.